# Spring security access role basics

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and going through simple Hello World Kind of Programs.

I got that example from here: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/springsecurity/SpringSecurityCustomLoginForm.html

I am not able to get the correct flow of application.

I found in Spring HTML Form, written like,

"
method='POST'>

What will happen when someone writes like j_spring_security_check?

Also at security.xml ie server side,

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/failLogin" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logoff" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="roseindia" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

So what will happen when request like (http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityCheckExample/index)
will first hit.

it will go to authentication manager tag or http tag?

Also, I found some where it was written as,

what should be cam_create in this context?

Also,
if we are checking uid and password from database then do we have to make one column over there for roles and give every uid and pswd some roles, or how is it??

I am sorry to ask silly things but I want to clear my doubt.
Also I dint found some good tutorial on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Q. What will happen when someone writes like j_spring_security_check?

---> `j_spring_security_check` is the login-processing-url which maps to the `filterProcessesUrl` property of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. This enables the Authentication using Spring Security. But remember you have to have input fields `username` and `password` names as `j_username` and `j_password`.

> Q. what will happen when request like (http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityCheckExample/index) will first hit?

--->

1. Checked whether user is logged in or not, if not user is taken to login page.
2. User logs-in using credentials. If credentials are valid then user is taken to `/index` page, and if credentials are invalid then user is taken to **authentication-failure-url="/failLogin"**.

> it will go to authentication manager tag or http tag?

---> It will neither go to `http` tag nor `authentication-manager` tag. XML values will be read by Spring classes and filters at server startup.

> Also, if we are checking uid and password from database then do we have to make one column over there for roles and give every uid and pswd some roles, or how is it?

---> Yes, you need to assign role to each user and you will have to store roles in database too.

Check [Spring Security Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) for more info.

Comment: For answer on point 2.
Where is that mapping done, that when request like /index is given for the first time then it open login.jsp.
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index">
above line only says if login is success go to index.jsp

Comment: when i tried to run the example present in link below.
(http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/springsecurity/SpringSecurityCustomLoginForm.html)

i have not made any database and still I am able to access the after login success page when i provide credentials like "admin" and "roseindia"                                                          then what is the use of "ROLE_USER" in this context. what does ROLE_USER does?
is it something like when i give this credential then that person will be assigned "ROLE_USER" or how is it.

Comment: ans to 1st comment : because you have mentioned `login-page="/login"` in `form-login` tag.

Comment: ans to 2nd comment: exactly you are correct in case ROLE_USER. in case of uname and pwd you are giving it in xml `user name="admin" password="roseindia"`. It is for test purpose

Comment: for 1st answer, I am only telling that /login request comes then 
 <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/failLogin" />

my controller is called which is calling login.jsp and if credentials passed is correct then call index.jsp.

my question is when i pass /index then it is showing me login.jsp page and which line is redirecting that thing.

Comment: for 2nd answer
if that is the case then if I pass like this
<user name="admin" password="roseindia" authorities="abs" />
and in 
<intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="abs" />
then it should work right....but it is not and giving exception at Loading time only

Comment: `authorities="abs"` is wrong because you have to define roles with prefix `"ROLE_"`. Check using `"ROLE_ABS"`

Comment: `which line is redirecting that thing?`. No line is redirecting, you are directly opening login page by making request to it.